# Surprise printing to string (common lisp)

Tags: common-lisp

Following the documentation for [WITH-OUTPUT-TO-STRING](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_w_out_.htm) and
[GET-OUTPUT-STREAM-STRING](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_get_ou.htm), I expect the following to work, and they do:

```
(print
 (with-output-to-string (sb nil)
   (format sb "~A " "hello, ")
   (format sb "~A~&" "world")
   sb))

(print
 (let ((sb (make-string-output-stream)))
   (format sb "~A " "hello, ")
   (format sb "~A~&" "world")
   (get-output-stream-string sb)))
```

However, the following, which is close to one of the examples in
[WITH-OUTPUT-TO-STRING](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_w_out_.htm), does not:

```
(print
 (with-output-to-string (sb (make-array
                             '(0)
                             :element-type 'base-char
                             :fill-pointer 0
                             :adjustable t))
   (format sb "~A " "hello, ")
   (format sb "~A~&" "world")
   sb))
```

producing, instead, the output stream, itself, rather than the string held within:

```
#<SB-IMPL::FILL-POINTER-OUTPUT-STREAM {1005FBE523}>
```

I have not been able to find a way to extract the string inside the output
stream. I suspect that it has something to do with dynamic extent, but my
understanding falters, here.

Obviously, I have kosher ways of achieving the desired result, so I am merely
curious to discover my misunderstanding of the language.

Because the documentation says that the results are undefined for
GET-OUTPUT-STREAM-STRING on a stream *not* created by MAKE-STRING-OUTPUT-STREAM, I
am not surprised that the following doesn't work:

```
(print
 (with-output-to-string (sb (make-array
                             '(0)
                             :element-type 'base-char
                             :fill-pointer 0
                             :adjustable t))
   (format sb "~A " "hello, ")
   (format sb "~A~&" "world")
   (get-output-stream-string sb)))
```

but I'd still be grateful for finding a way of extracting the string in my third
example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that [WITH-OUTPUT-TO-STRING](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_w_out_.htm#with-output-to-string) returns values in two different ways:

1. if you give it no string or `NIL`, then it creates a string and returns it.
2. if you give it a string, then it returns the result values of the last body form.

Your code:

```
(print
 (with-output-to-string (sb (make-array   ; creates a string
                             '(0)
                             :element-type 'base-char
                             :fill-pointer 0
                             :adjustable t))
   (format sb "~A " "hello, ")
   (format sb "~A~&" "world")
   sb)   ; you return the stream (which makes not much sense), but not the string
   )
```

You have created a string by calling `MAKE-ARRAY`. There it is. Use it. To do so, you usually need to have it bound to some variable.

Example how to return the string:

```
(let ((s (make-array '(0)
                     :element-type 'base-char
                     :fill-pointer 0
                     :adjustable t)))
  (with-output-to-string (sb s)
    (format sb "~A " "hello, ")
    (format sb "~A~&" "world"))
  s)
```

or

```
(let ((s (make-array '(0)
                     :element-type 'base-char
                     :fill-pointer 0
                     :adjustable t)))
  (with-output-to-string (sb s)
    (format sb "~A " "hello, ")
    (format sb "~A~&" "world")
    s))
```

In the last case `with-output-to-string` returns the value, because it got a string which it uses as the target for output.

Comment: Interesting that in my first example, where I passed `nil` to `with-output-to-string`, that the string and the output stream are somehow conflated, so that I can use the variable `sb` as both an output stream (to which I send output from `format`) and a string (which I return from the outer form).

Comment: @Reb.Cabin: if you pass nothing or NIL, the string will be returned. If you pass a string, the values of the last form will be returned. In the first example, the value of sb is ignored.